# Integrating $\int{\frac{x}{x+1}}\,dx$

Tags: integration

None of the methods I know can solve this easily. I tried integrating by parts, but it essentially leads you to the equation $\int{\frac{x}{x+1}}\,dx=\int{\frac{x}{x+1}}\,dx$, which isn't very helpful.

Using Wolfram Alpha, it seems like you need to rewrite the integrand:

$$\frac{x}{x+1}=1-\frac{1}{x+1}$$

That makes it easy to integrate. Is this some method that others know about? I never came across a problem like this before, so it's interesting for me. In what cases should one rewrite the integrand like this in order to make integration easier? I'm asking this so that I can be prepared for the next time a question like this stumps me.

Comment: Two words: long division.

Comment: Thank you. So in which cases should I use long division? When I have a fraction that I can't seem to integrate using traditional methods?

Comment: Just substitute $x = y-1$ ($dx=dy$)?

Comment: Long division isn't a method of integration - it's a way to rewrite the integrand. Notice that we can't use a logarithm nor a substitution outright, and parts doesn't help at all. Use long division when the degree of the numerator is at least that of the denominator.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I just realized that the substitution suggested by kennytm allows you to rewrite as $$\frac{y-1}{y}=1-\frac1y=1-\frac{1}{x+1}$$ so it does help in this case! (And it's the same thing as suggested by WA)

Comment: It seems you are happy with your answer. The general way to do this would be to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division Can be good to remember when your polynomials are a bit larger.

Comment: I'll also keep your suggestion in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a standard technique: $$\frac{x}{x+1} = \frac{x+(1-1)}{x+1}=\frac{x+1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+1}$$

Notice all I did was to add $0$.

Comment: I've never thought of it like that before, so it seems quite ingenious!

Comment: Two standard techniques that students often underestimate the power of: adding $0$ and multiplying by $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Just another take, in case Bye_Worlds ingenuity escapes you.

Suppose you need to address $\int\frac{x}{x+1} \,dx$, as given.

One option is to use "u-substitution": Let $u = x+1 \implies du=dx.$ But also $u = x+1 \implies x = u-1$

That gives us $$\int \frac {u-1}{u}\,du = \int \left (1 - \frac 1u\right) \,du$$

$$ = u - \ln(u) + c$$

Back substitution gives us $$ (x+1) - \ln(x+1) + c$$

Now notice, we can absorb the $1$ from $x + 1$ to get $$x - \ln (x+1) + \underbrace{(c +1)}_C$$

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer! I feel really bad saying this though (and really mean, given the fact that you spent some time writing this out), but I essentially *did* figure this out if you look at my comment on the question, thanks to kennytm's suggestion. That being said, I want to thank you wholeheartedly for answering my question – it does quite well to elucidate this particular method :)

Comment: Oh my, I didn't read the helpful comments below your question. At any rate, you are most welcome!